# How to select the row having any two columns not null

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the one shown in the image.

[image]

I need to select the rows which have more than 2 columns having non zero values. So the highlighted yellow ones only need to be selected.
I tried

```py
df[(df.iloc[:, 1:13] != 0.0).any(1)]
```

but it's for any 1 column how to do it for more than 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to generate a True/False filter as:

`index_filter = df.apply(lambda x: True if sum(x != 0) > 1 else False, axis=1)`

`index_filter` will be `True` at the indices where at least two of the dataframe columns are not 0.

Now you can filter the dataframe as `df[index_filter]`.

Another alternative would be:

```
num_cols_not_zero = df.ne(0).sum(axis=1)
df[num_cols_not_zero.gt(1)]
```

If specific columns are necessary, the more performance intensive but code simple version would be by creating a subset dataframe as `df[<list of cols of interest>]` and substitute `df` with this new version in the above examples of `index_filter` or `num_cols_not_zero`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for selecting in all columns:

```
main_df.loc[:,main_df.notnull().sum() > 1]
```

Try this if you want to select columns your self. This is not nice looking code, I haven't had any coffee yet, but it does the job.

```
idx_lst = [x if i > 1 else None for x, i in zip(main_df.index, main_df[['C', 'D']].notnull().sum())]
main_df[main_df.index.isin(idx_lst)]
```

To change criteria for filtering, adjust the IF statement in the first line of code.

Comment: it counts how many not null values are in the row and returns them if condition is met.

Comment: This is based on all the available columns. But how to add selective columns. I Tried main_df.loc[:,main_df.loc[:,'C','D'].notnull().sum() > 1] but didn't work

Comment: @ragendthsfdcpk check my edit :)